# Java Eclipse open 2 tabs eclipse.exe and project

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I wake up and start eclipse like every single day the open a screen and a splash screen later it opens the eclipse window but the previous remains open this is a kinda annoying have 2 open tabs for eclipse... I want when eclipse opens the other tab closes is a black window with nothing in it...

Here is my `eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

please take a look to the image.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: What happens with a current version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve my problem adding the line to the **FIRST LINE** in `eclipse.ini` file

something like

```
-vm 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

yes in 2 lines not in a single line.

my eclipse.ini is like this ready now.

```
-vm 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

i hope really helps somebody.